# magento2 : so many jquery & require.js error when activating ssl

Tags: magento2, jquery, requirejs, ssl

Magento2: so many jquery & require.js error when activating SSL. On Backend & Frontend Both.

Is there any common problem?

Error screenshot: Front End

[image]

Error screenshot: BackEnd

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**You need to perform below actions**

- Flush cache
- Check console if you are getting 404 error for files then 
  deploy static content

  `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
- If still facing 404 error then check permission of pub static directory.

Comment: no there is no 404 error. i just update the question and uploaded error screenshot. i tried given solution many times. Even i was delete all files of pub/static except .htaccess & also delete var/cache. and then run given command

Comment: try permission 777 to pub/static directory and re deploy static content .
It may be because of permission,as magento updates require config .may be it is unable to update becasue of permission.
you can correct permission after checking it.

Comment: pub/static folder permission is - 777 & all inner directories permission is 775. is that not correct? also i updated screenshot error of backend too